# jQuery Waypoints only triggers when element hits top of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

The title basically says it. It does not matter what I put in the offset param, it only fires when the element hits the top of the window.

```
 $('.waypoint').waypoint({
        handler: function(direction) {
            console.log('hit');
        }
    }, {offset: '100%'});
```

I have also tried setting context manually, but the results are the same.

Comment: I think that waypoint works with a only parameter. You are introducing two parameters, try merging both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the `offset` as other key of the same JSON which contains `handler`

```
$('.waypoint').waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {
        console.log('hit');
    },
    offset: '100%'});
```

I have seen this other way in the official documentation:

```
 $('.waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {
  console.log('hit');
 }, {
   offset: '100%'
 })
```

Comment: Thank you, my eyes totally missed that!